# Delete specific Rows without using Do Until loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Hi I have a code that trim a cell value and deletes the row if it matches a criteria.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim ch As String, str As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim last As Long

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Source")
last = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
i = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Do Until ws1.Cells(i, 1) = ""

    ch = Left(ws1.Cells(i, 6), 3)
    str = 314

        If ch = str Then

            ws1.Cells(i, 6).Rows.EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    i = i + 1
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

My code works but it is very slow on execution because of the do until loop. Is there any way to do this other than using do until loop? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it to a For loop. This will allow you to cut out a bit of code. I would also recommend adding static variables outside of the loops. This will remove any unnecessary processing. I ran this and it seemed to run quite quickly.

```
Sub main()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ch As String, str As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim last As Long

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Source")
    last = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    str = 314

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For i = last To 2 Step -1
        If Left(ws1.Cells(i, 6), 3) = str Then
            ws1.Cells(i, 6).Rows.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: It runs quickly. I've just revised your loop from "For i = 1 To last" to "For i = last To 2 Step -1" so that it won't skip any row once a column is deleted. Thanks. :)

Comment: Glad to hear this works for you!! Good luck on this project!

Answer (score 0):

Build a string first then do ONE delete.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim i As Long, DelRange As String
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row 'Doesn't matter which way you go when you delete in one go
    If Left(Cells(i, 6), 3) = "314" Then DelRange = DelRange & "," & i & ":" & i 'Change the "314" as you see fit
Next i
Range(Right(DelRange, Len(DelRange) - 1)).Delete
End Sub
```

I didn't bother turning screen updating or calculation off because you are only making one edit and you probably want to recalculate after that edit.